# increasing the values in a dataset to the highest number that they currently encompass

Tags: r, dataframe

UPDATE THE QUESTION:

Zephryl already provided an awesome answer to this question, below I wanted to add additional details to my initial question.

The data is

```
data <- structure(list(country = c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
                       "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Austria", "Austria", 
                       "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                       "Austria", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
                       "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
                       "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal"), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
                  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
                  9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), levels = c("1000", "1200", 
                                                                      "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1750", "1800"), class = "factor"), fit.0.025quant = c(0.828858435568409, 2.49016922773755, 2.65828836880409, 
               2.66581093505707, 2.57548603944065, 1.67885386266028, 0.767937801519583, 
               0.689014091834041, 0.66513695912892, 0.663699022639656, 0.678689217926065, 
               0.67888578207667, 0.678889008309296, 0.678889067277956, 0.678889008315121, 
               0.678885782094281, 0.67868921794039, 0.663699022695475, 0.753024027011781, 
               1.56176460225556, 1.66925563033888, 1.56663639224176, 0.757961319722877, 
               0.690760522079772, 0.688181548019768, 0.760878851337501, 
               1.5613478080279, 0.664563945566996, 0.68508607246818, 0.737286017774939, 
               1.5119543712026, 0.819687233979314, 1.60507738574301, 1.66679441254118, 
               1.68306812289583, 1.66919593888341), fit.mean = c(1.13400448293661, 
                                                                 2.87830024613312, 2.98840123437886, 2.99270845416986, 2.93292120022681, 
                                                                 2.00001375693309, 1.06700462995692, 1.00618961591289, 1.0007893132799, 
                                                                 1.00004363941275, 1.00003146052876, 1.00003107297182, 1.00003106386579, 
                                                                 1.00003106366991, 1.00003106386888, 1.00003107297307, 1.00003146052807, 
                                                                 1.00004363941059, 1.06578800415204, 1.92791273808794, 2.00911809484502, 
                                                                 1.92938242492218, 1.05953000948759, 1.00731995863015, 1.00551539597356, 
                                                                 1.0617929411748, 1.93397100841674, 1.00049922917461, 1.00391214501682, 
                                                                 1.04414180746079, 1.89014845620677, 1.1133844912819, 1.94890869596221, 
                                                                 1.99253538304467, 2.00313100995317, 2.00364556256633), fit.0.975quant = c(1.5548453965449, 
                                                                                                                                           3.17193689185671, 3.30217150519806, 3.30887034452248, 3.23188378430461, 
                                                                                                                                           2.32122877803568, 1.42445510409649, 1.33229333739629, 1.33797676580827, 
                                                                                                                                           1.33651739528035, 1.32146593655336, 1.32126741860939, 1.32126414685111, 
                                                                                                                                           1.32126408690283, 1.32126414685902, 1.32126741859377, 1.32146593653428, 
                                                                                                                                           1.33651739521255, 1.43806634680653, 2.23154393918938, 2.35542858727393, 
                                                                                                                                           2.23131692404623, 1.40982833868788, 1.33388203589275, 1.33103300867831, 
                                                                                                                                           1.41382643372889, 2.24644777498799, 1.33739126255841, 1.32804123237336, 
                                                                                                                                           1.38436190848754, 2.18404788457664, 1.4941065137638, 2.25306205937895, 
                                                                                                                                           2.30955823803133, 2.32596318832388, 2.34217586698821)), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 16L, 17L, 18L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L), class = "data.frame")
```

The question is the following:

For Italy in date ‘1000’, the values for ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and ‘fit.0.975quant’ are `0.6736376`, `1.0000012`  and `1.326401`. The highest number that currently lies within the boundaries is 1. I want all three values to get lifted, so that they cover as entirely as possible the continuum between 1.01-1.99.

And so should happen for every row in a dataset. For example, for Italy in date ‘1200’, the values for ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and ‘fit.0.975quant’ are 2.5193345, 2.8869927 and 3.168365. The highest number that currently lies within the boundaries is 3. I want all three values to get lifted, so that they cover as entirely as possible the continuum between 3.01-3.99.

**So it is like lifting ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and‘fit.0.975quant’ to the uppermost number that currently lies within its boundaries, so that all three cover as entirely as possible the continuum of some exact number.**

If it happens that the values for ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and ‘fit.0.975quant’ already lie entirely within the boundaries of some number (like 5.01-5.99), then they should be stretched over as entirely as possible to cover the continuum of their number.

So, if it is 1.01, 1.34, 1.68, the latter '1.68' should get stretched toward 1.99.

Guys, I hope my explanations are not confusing.

Do you think there can be a suitable code that automatically transforms the values in a whole dataset as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply()` to find the difference between the minimum and floor of the maximum for each row:

```r
add <- apply(dat[, 3:5], 1, \(x) floor(max(x))) - apply(dat[, 3:5], 1, min)
add <- ifelse(add < -0.01, 0, add + 0.01)
dat[, 3:5] <- dat[, 3:5] + add
```

Result:

```r
#> head(dat, 10)
   country date fit.0.025quant fit.mean fit.0.975quant
1    Italy 1000           1.01 1.315146       1.735987
2    Italy 1200           3.01 3.398131       3.691768
3    Italy 1300           3.01 3.340113       3.653883
4    Italy 1400           3.01 3.336898       3.653059
5    Italy 1500           3.01 3.367435       3.666398
6    Italy 1600           2.01 2.331160       2.652375
7    Italy 1700           1.01 1.309067       1.666517
8    Italy 1750           1.01 1.327176       1.653279
9    Italy 1800           1.01 1.345652       1.682840
10 Austria 1000           1.01 1.346345       1.682818
```

Note, if there are cases where the range between min and max is >0.98 in your actual data, this approach won’t keep them within two integers. You’ll have to decide how you want to handle those cases.

**Edit:**

To have each row cover the range x.01 - x.99:

```r
mins <- do.call(pmin, dat[, 3:5])
maxes <- do.call(pmax, dat[, 3:5])

mult <- 0.98 / (maxes - mins)
add <- floor(maxes) + 0.01

dat[, 3:5] <- (dat[, 3:5] - mins) * mult + add
```

Result:

```
#> head(dat, 10)
   country date fit.0.025quant fit.mean fit.0.975quant
1    Italy 1000           1.01 1.421913           1.99
2    Italy 1200           3.01 3.567915           3.99
3    Italy 1300           3.01 3.512437           3.99
4    Italy 1400           3.01 3.508180           3.99
5    Italy 1500           3.01 3.543650           3.99
6    Italy 1600           2.01 2.499958           2.99
7    Italy 1700           1.01 1.456425           1.99
8    Italy 1750           1.01 1.493199           1.99
9    Italy 1800           1.01 1.498882           1.99
10 Austria 1000           1.01 1.499906           1.99
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want the new values to cover entirely the continuum of (for example) 1.01-1.99. That is, it has to be not 1.01-1.45, but to be as close as possible to 1.01-1.99. Do you think the R-code can do that?